# MySQL query performance of Date sorted data

Tags: mysql, performance

I found some articles and questions on this issue but not sure if I got the answer. very new to db modeling so please bear with me 
My use case is:

- Save user activities: I'm doing this by creating a one table and saving all user activities. The table has a ID, user_id(foreign key), time(Datetime), type(varchar), description
- Query the table for activities for a user for a time frame and potentially for a activity type.

My concern is the performance when the table has a large number of rows. My steps that I think will help improve is

- index the user_id
- index the time

Then I can query for "user_is = 'abc' and time > somedate" or "user_is = 'abc' and time > somedate and type = xyz"

should I index type too? will having too many index have performance issues (when inserting new row or querying)?
What else can I do. Any advise will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this question would be better suited at the [dba.se] site. Voted to close/migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is presumably something like:

```
select a.*
from activities a
where user_is = 'abc' and time > somedate
```

or

```
where user_is = 'abc' and time > somedate and type = xyz
```

The best index for the first query is `activities(user_is, time)` and for the second `activities(user_id, type, time)`.